# Create a theme that look like Commodore 64 on Ubuntu?

Tags: themes, debian, mint

I did use Commodore OS Vision but it has stop making updates many years ago. I was wondering is it possible to do a theme that looks and feels like that on Ubuntu? I really miss it and that "neon light" around of the windows.

Maybe even edit the name in boot and splashscreen?

This is what I meant: [Commodore OS Vision](https://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=commodore)

Screenshot:
[image]
Image from: https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Gvp5cztsXCk/TsE3wT8uusI/AAAAAAAAAWc/-bxUAl-Xk1M/s1600/Screenshot.png

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course it's possible. You have to do the following:

- Download the latest copy of Commodore OS Vision
- Find the theme files and components for that version
- Update everything to work with the latest version of GNOME
- Eventually: Package the theme and release it

This may take some time, but definitely possible if you have that.